# More than 40 characters in SAP Variant Conditions for Quotation printouts

Tags: sap-erp

Currently we print the variant condition (description) with the limitation of 40 characters maximum in our Quotation documents. We are on SAP ECC.

Our sales department would like to print Quotation documents that allow descriptive texts of >40 characters. A sufficient length would be about 60 characters, ideally 70 characters.

What would be a good solution to maintain longer texts on variant conditions and print them on the form?

I have researched but somehow was not able to find a solution path.

Comment: Is that a programming question? How is C++ related to the question?

Comment: what exactly are you printing? give the screenshot, printform name and exact steps how are you doing this